# Json to csv conversion taking very huge time on large files in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am trying to convert a very large json file to csv.The code works well with smaller files but taking  so much time while running the same code on larger files
i tested it first on 91 mb file containing 80,000 entries and it took around 45 minutes but after that for a bigger files containing 300,000 entries it took around 5 hours. is there some way to do it through multi processing? i am a beginner python programmer so dont have idea to use multi processing or multi threading in python. here is my code

```
import json
import time
import pandas as pd

csv_project=pd.DataFrame([],columns=['abstract','authors','n_citation',"references","title","venue","year",'id'])


with open('test.json','r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
j=0
for k,i in enumerate(data):

    if '{' in i and '}' in i:

        j+=1
        dictionary=json.loads(i)
        csv_project=csv_project.append(dictionary,ignore_index=True)
    else:
        pass 
    if j == 10000:
        print(str(k)+'number of entries done')
        csv_project.to_csv('data.csv')
        j=0
csv_project.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Any useful help will be appreciated.
edit here is the sample json format .

```
    {"abstract": "AdaBoost algorithm based on Haar-like features can achieves high accuracy (above 95%) in object detection.", 
"authors": ["Zheng Xu", "Runbin Shi", "Zhihao Sun", "Yaqi Li", "Yuanjia Zhao", "Chenjian Wu"], 
"n_citation": 0,
 "references": ["0a11984c-ab6e-4b75-9291-e1b700c98d52", "1f4152a3-481f-4adf-a29a-2193a3d4303c", "3c2ddf0a-237b-4d17-8083-c90df5f3514b", "522ce553-29ea-4e0b-9ad3-0ed4eb9de065", "579e5f24-5b13-4e92-b255-0c46d066e306", "5d0b987d-eed9-42ce-9bf3-734d98824f1b", "80656b4d-b24c-4d92-8753-bdb965bcd50a", "d6e37fb1-5f7e-448e-847b-7d1f1271c574"],
 "title": "A Heterogeneous System for Real-Time Detection with AdaBoost",
 "venue": "high performance computing and communications",
 "year": 2016,
 "id": "001eef4f-1d00-4ae6-8b4f-7e66344bbc6e"}


{"abstract": "In this paper, a kind of novel jigsaw EBG structure is designed and applied into conformal antenna array",
 "authors": ["Yufei Liang", "Yan Zhang", "Tao Dong", "Shan-wei Lu"], 
"n_citation": 0, 
"references": [], 
"title": "A novel conformal jigsaw EBG structure design", 
"venue": "international conference on conceptual structures", 
"year": 2016, 
"id": "002e0b7e-d62f-4140-b015-1fe29a9acbaa"}
```

Comment: At a glance, the biggest problem I see is that you are reassigning a new appended `pd.DataFrame` in each loop, which takes a lot of processing power.  Also manually parsing a `json` file (even partially) after `import json` is like building your own car from scratch instead of driving the one you already bought.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see if the reading of the file or the processing is the bottleneck?

Comment: @jdrd reading takes no  time.its writing which is taking time

Comment: @Idlehands as i have mentioned i am a beginner python programmer and still learning. can you elaborate a little how to overcome this solution

Comment: There's no shame in being a beginner, we've all been there.  I'm just trying to point out where your bottleneck is.  Having said that, if you can share the structure of your `json` as an [MCVE] it'll help us bring light to improvement.

Comment: Did you only want to run a maximum of 10,000 entries from your `json` file?

Comment: i have updated the json format in my description. kindly check @Idlehands

Comment: Could you add your expected CSV file output as well for the JSON example?

Comment: @Idlehands when i was trying to save more than 10000 entries it was giving me some error. so i used append for files having entries more than 10,000

Comment: Is your `json` file in [json lines](http://jsonlines.org/) format (i.e. each line itself starts and ends with `{}` without a comma at the end, which is a `json` object itself)? Are you able to just execute `json.load(f)` without trouble? I'm trying to understand your logic of `if '{' in i and '}' in i:`

Comment: @Idlehands actually its dblp dataset which contains a huge amount of research data. before i was trying to use simple json parsing and than conversion to csv but it was not converting it properly. this is not purely my logic i took help from online forums and tried to run it. this one works flawlessly for me uptill now but having issues with large running time

Comment: in others word i have very rare understanding of what is going on here :P @Idlehands

Comment: Ah, welcome to the understanding of "it works!" and "it works *efficiently!*".  I think @Daniel's answer should help, but if not then if you could update your question with the first 2 lines of your `json` file (and maybe the last 2 lines as well) then I can fully understand the input structure before attempting an answer.

Comment: @Idlehands i have updated first two entries of my json file. daniel answer is not working and giving error while processing 14th entry of json

Comment: @idlehands can i have your personal email? I need some assistance regarding python.

Comment: It's best to have the community help you instead of a dedicated individual, since I'm not all that experienced myself either.  If you have a new question just post a new one, I'm sure many others are happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep all your data in memory, once as lines and once as dataframe. This could slow down your processing.

Using the `csv`-module would allow you, to process the file in streaming mode:

```
import json
import csv

with open('test.json') as lines, open('data.csv', 'w') as output:
    output = csv.DictWriter(output, ['abstract','authors','n_citation',"references","title","venue","year",'id'])
    output.writeheader()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == '{' and line[-1] == '}':
            output.writerow(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: this is giving me error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 10, in <module>
    output.writerow(json.loads(line))
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0144' in position 667: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: thanks alot you are life saver (y). just added encoding='utf-8' in file opening syntax and it worked but there is space of 1 line in each entry how to over come this

Comment: like for example there should be 80000 lines but now it is showing 160000 lines. one line is extra after each entry

Comment: Add `lineterminator='\n'` as an argument to `csv.DictWriter(...)`

Comment: thanks alot guys you both are too good for me today. having a bad day and than you guys come and save my day (y)

Comment: Hi Daniel i am. Applying LDA on same dblp dataset but it is giving me null dimensions. Can you guide me exactly what is causing null?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're reading a [`json lines`](http://jsonlines.org/) file, which might look something like this:

```
{key1: value1, key2: [value2, value3, value4], key3: value3}
{key1: value4, key2: [value5, value6], key3: value7}
```

Notice no commas at the end, and each line itself is a valid `json` format.

Lucky for you, pandas can read the `json lines` file directly like this:

```
pd.read_json('test.json', lines=True)
```

Since your column names are exactly the same as your `json` keys, there's no need for you to set up a blank `DataFrame` ahead of time.  The `read_json` will do all the parsing for you.  Example:

```
df = pd.read_json('test.json', lines=True)
print(df)

                                            abstract  ...   year
0  AdaBoost algorithm based on Haar-like features...  ...   2016
1  In this paper, a kind of novel jigsaw EBG stru...  ...   2016

[2 rows x 8 columns]
```

Even luckier, if you are limited by size, there is a `chunksize` argument you can use which turns the `.read_json` method into a generator:

```
json_reader = pd.read_json('test.json', lines=True, chunksize=10000)
```

Now when you iterate through `json_reader`, each time it will output a `DataFrame` of the next 10,000 rows from the `json` file.  Example:

```
for j in json_reader:
  print(j)

                                            abstract  ...   year
0  AdaBoost algorithm based on Haar-like features...  ...   2016
1  In this paper, a kind of novel jigsaw EBG stru...  ...   2016

[2 rows x 8 columns]
                                            abstract  ...   year
2  AdaBoost algorithm based on Haar-like features...  ...   2016
3  In this paper, a kind of novel jigsaw EBG stru...  ...   2016

[2 rows x 8 columns]
                                            abstract  ...   year
4  AdaBoost algorithm based on Haar-like features...  ...   2016
5  In this paper, a kind of novel jigsaw EBG stru...  ...   2016

[2 rows x 8 columns]
```

Combining all these newfound knowledge, you can use the `chunksize=10000` and output the chunked `DataFrame` as a separate `csv` like so:

```
for i, df in enumerate(json_reader):
  df.to_csv('my_csv_file_{}'.format(i))
```

Here you notice I combined `enumerate()`  function so we can get an auto-incremented index number, and `str.format()` function to append the index number to the generated `csv` file.

[You can see an example here on Repl.it.](https://repl.it/repls/OrnateRaggedGigahertz)